# How do I bundle existing Reset(), MoveNext(), and Current into a yield-based iterator in C#?

Tags: c#, iterator, yield-return

I have a simple class, MyClass, which already has the Reset(), MoveNext(), and Current pieces. But it doesn't provide an iterator, it just exposes those components.

I started with this:

```
public IEnumerator<MyClass> GetEnumerator()
{
    Reset();
    while (MoveNext())
        yield return Current;
}
```

Which triggers the following error:

CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'IEnumerator' because 'IEnumerator' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I tried a bunch of other approaches, but no joy.

Would someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Which collection are you trying to iterate with foreach?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I don't understand how the code in your question can produce the mentioned compiler error.

Comment: I worked it out - I needed to add this method:         System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your code does something like

```
foreach(var variable in collection.GetEnumerator())
{
 //do some stuff
}
```

You can leave out the GetEnumerator call. If you class implements IEnumerable it wil be called automatically.

So just:

```
foreach(var variable in collection)
{
//do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Key points:

- You should call `foreach` on the collection, not on the enumerator
- Collection itself doesn't need to implement `MoveNext` and `Current`, the enumerator does
- When you implement `GetEnumerator()` like `IEnumerator<T>` with `yield` statements, `MoveNext` and `Current` are implemented automatically, parameter type `T` shouldn't be exactly `MyClass`

[Documentation on CS1579](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1579):

> To iterate through a collection using the foreach statement, the
>   collection must meet the following requirements:
>
> - Its type must include a public parameterless GetEnumerator method    whose return type is either class, struct, or interface type.
> - The return type of the GetEnumerator method must contain a public property named Current and a public parameterless method named
>     MoveNext whose return type is Boolean.

This is the example of simple collection of numbers from 1 to 5:

```
class MyCollection
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int index = 1; index <= 5; index++) { 
            yield return index;
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can iterate through it using `foreach`:

```
var collection = new MyCollection();
foreach(var element in collection) {
    Console.Write(element);
}
```